# How to solve this error related to a WordPress upgrade on the server?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress error on live website:

[image: WordPress error on live website]

I can not understand what the error means. This error happened when I updated the WordPress version.

Error like this :

> Deprecated: date.php is deprecated since version 5.3.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-date-query.php instead. in /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4967
> Deprecated: class-oembed.php is deprecated since version 5.3.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php instead. in /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4967
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_recovery_mode() in /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-includes/load.php:870 Stack trace: #0 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-includes/load.php(754): wp_is_recovery_mode() #1 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-settings.php(303): wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() #2 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-config.php(89): require_once('/home/stageberi...') #3 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/stageberi...') #4 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/stageberi...') #5 /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/stageberi...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/stageberide/public_html/public/blog/wp-includes/load.php on line 870

Comment: Seems like there may have been an issue when the update happened.  Might need to reinstall the core files to ensure they were all updated.

Comment: Can you access dashboard?

Comment: The question here was rather hard to understand. I have rewritten it so a native English speaker could understand it. Please check I have not changed your meaning.

Comment: If the problem is that your plugins/themes do not work with the newer version of WordPress, then find out what old version you were using, and downgrade back to that. However, you may have a problem if the new version of WP migrated your db to a newer format.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, create backup on your hosting provider. then,
Try downloading WordPress again, access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel (consult your hosting provider’s documentation for specifics on these), and delete then replace your copies of everything on the server except the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/ directory with fresh copies from the download. This will effectively replace all of your core files without damaging your content and settings.

Some uploaders tend to be unreliable when overwriting files, so don’t forget to delete the original files before replacing them.

Comment: this is on the server and every content are important so I can not delete that all contents and not replace with new one

Comment: Thats why i said to make backup first. Content will stay, just wordpress core will be replaced